# Distance measure of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fractals, geometric-measure-theory

In Mattila's *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension*, we have on page 59 that given a finite measure $\mu$ compactly supported on a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we can define a finite measure $\delta(\mu)$ compactly supported on its distance set $D(A):=\left\{\lVert x-y \rVert : x,y \in A \right\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
    \delta(\mu)(B)= \int \mu(\{y:|x-y|\in B\}) d \mu(x).
$$
It is then claimed that we have, for any $f \in C_0^\infty$,
$$
\delta{(f)}(r)= \int (\sigma_{r}^{n-1} *f)f,
$$
where $\sigma_{r}^{n-1}$ is the typical measure on the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$. How is $\delta(f)$ defined here? I thought we could only input a measure.

Comment: Is $f\in L^1$? It should be written somewhere

Comment: Yes, it is, and I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Then it is most probably intended that $f$ is the measure $f\,d\mathcal L^n$, where $\mathcal L^n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Then why is it that it takes a real number as an input instead of a set?

Comment: Because $\delta(f)$ is also a function. Again, integrable functions are a special case of measures. But you really should check for yourself that the two formulas you wrote coincide when $f=\mu$.